# How to join two tables with where clause in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on friend request and notification system ! when user sends friend request,notification being received by second user! when second user accepts it, notification table updates with 1 in did_read field. I have tried but it shows me all notifications including read (did_read = 1). show me where is the problem in my code please. Thanks

My function is below

```
public function manage_friend_req($loginuser){


    $this->db->select('from_user,to_user,did_read,avatar');
    $this->db->from('notifications');
    $this->db->join('users','users.username = notifications.from_user');
    $this->db->where(array('notifications.to_user'=>$loginuser));
    $this->db->where('notifications.did_read',0);
    $query = $this->db->get();        
    return $query->result();

 }  // 'did_read' field in database is an enum.
```

Comment: user the $this->db->last_query(); and checking the your query in phpmyadmin

Comment: Maybe you should use only one `where` like this: `$this->db->where(array('notifications.to_user'=>$loginuser, 'notifications.did_read' =>0));`

Comment: I have tried it before this but no it shows me all records including 1 and 0

Answer (score 0):

1. $this->db->or_where('notifications.did_read',0); //used or
2. $this->db->where('notifications.did_read',0); //used and

Comment: Thank you for reply !! what should I change in this code when 'did_read' filed in database is an enum ?